# iptables equivalent in windows-xp,win7?

Tags: windows-7, iptables

I want to do port forwarding in win7,what's the iptables equivalent in win7?

Answer (score 3):

After a little search on google, I found [WinpkFilter](http://www.ntkernel.com/w&p.php?id=7)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `netsh` for Display/change network configuration of a computer

`netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=xxx connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=yyy protocol=tcp`

[more info](https://parsiya.net/blog/2016-06-07-windows-netsh-interface-portproxy/)